# Json to Java Object - Failed due to identical fields

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I am trying to convert a json to a java object. Since there are identical fields in the json, it throws an error like this.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Conflicting setter definitions for property "amount": 
com.gateway.model.Order#setAmount(1 params) vs com.gateway.model.Order#setAmount(1 params)
```

This is the json ( part related to my problem)

```
   "order":{  
      "amount":1.000,
      "chargeback":{  
         "amount":0,
         "currency":"BHD"
      },
   }
```

This is the relevant part of java class.

```
public class Order
{

    private double amount;
    Chargeback ChargebackObject;

    // Getter Methods

    public double getAmount()
    {
        return amount;


    // Setter Methods
    public void setAmount(double amount)
    {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}

class Chargeback
{
    private double amount;
    private String currency;

    // Getter Methods
    @JsonIgnore
    public double getAmount()
    {
        return amount;
    }

    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    public String getCurrency()
    {
        return currency;
    }

    // Setter Methods 

    public void setAmount(double cb_amount)
    {
        this.amount = cb_amount;
    }

    public void setCurrency(String currency)
    {
        this.currency = currency;
    }  
}
```

Please note that Chargeback class is in the Order.java file.

I have tried `@JsonIgnore` annotation and removing the `amount` in the `chargeback` class but still the error exists. Could someone please suggest a solution for this?

Comment: Seems like you have two methods with the same name (`setAmount`) between those two classes; you need to rename one of the properties or indicate to Jackson which is which. Try renaming your Order amount to "quantity" and setAmount to setQuantity, since it better expresses what you're trying to accomplish anyway.

Comment: @AustinSchäfer That was exactly the case. Well it was a huge class with lot of variables and methods and somehow I missed it. Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code, Try the code below. Basically, I have done the followings.

1. There was no getter and setter for Chargeback object inside Order, so it was addedd.
2. Commented out the @JsonIgnore annotations.

The classess are given below

```
class Chargeback {
      private double amount;
      private String currency;

      // Getter Methods
    //  @JsonIgnore
      public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
      }

    //  @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
      public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
      }

      // Setter Methods

      public void setAmount(double cb_amount) {
        this.amount = cb_amount;
      }

      public void setCurrency(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
      }
    }

    public class Order {
      private double amount;
      Chargeback ChargebackObject;

      public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
      }

      public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
      }

      public Chargeback getChargebackObject() {
        return ChargebackObject;
      }

      public void setChargebackObject(Chargeback chargebackObject) {
        ChargebackObject = chargebackObject;
      }
    }
```

Code to Test to generate Json is given below.

```
public class Test1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Chargeback chargeback = new Chargeback();
    chargeback.setAmount(1234.00);
    chargeback.setCurrency("BHD");
    Order order = new Order();
    order.setAmount(2345.00);
    order.setChargebackObject(chargeback);

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String toJson = null;
    try {
      toJson = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(order);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Complete Json = " + toJson);

// From Json String to Java Object
ObjectMapper mapper1 = new ObjectMapper();
Order order1 = mapper.readValue(toJson, Order.class);
System.out.println("Order Object -> " + order1);
  }
}
```

Generate json is given below.

```
{
  "amount" : 2345.0,
  "chargebackObject" : {
    "amount" : 1234.0,
    "currency" : "BHD"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sambit. But I want to convert a json to a java object. Anyway I will look into your suggestion since its a matter of changing ObjectMapper code. +1 :)

Comment: I have also updated the answer. Thanks for informing me.